# Related tables, filters and conditions

Tags: erp, navision, dynamics-nav

I have a new table where one of his fields is related to Table Items. I want to place a filter in one of the function fields Item Category pointing register the Item table, but do not know how this dual role. I hope it was not too confusing ..

Comment: Wich version of NAV?

Comment: I can't even imagine what are your trying to say here. >> Smells like Google Translate <<